# Issue with Livewire in Laravel: Data Not Being Sent Correctly

Tags: php, laravel

I am encountering an issue while attempting to insert data into the database using Livewire in Laravel. The challenge is related to sending data through a form within a modal. However, it appears that the data is not being transmitted correctly. Below is the relevant code from my Livewire component (Index.php) and the modal (index.blade.php).

```
{{-- modal --}}
<div wire:ignore.self class="modal fade" id="addBrandModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Adicionar Marcas</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
          </div>

          <form wire:submit.prevent="storeBrand()">

              <div class="modal-body">

                  <div class="mb-3">
                      <label>Nome da Marca</label>
                      <input type="text" wire:model.defer="name" class="form-control">
                      @error('name') <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small> @enderror
                  </div>

                  <div class="mb-3">
                      <label>Slug da Marca</label>
                      <input type="text" wire:model.defer="slug" class="form-control">
                      @error('slug') <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small> @enderror
                  </div>

                  <div class="mb-3">
                      <label><h6>Status</h6></label>
                      <input type="checkbox" wire:model.defer="status"> Marcado=Oculto, Não Marcado=Visível
                      @error('status') <small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small> @enderror
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar alterações</button>
                  </div>

              </div>
          </form>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>



<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Brand;


use App\Models\Brand;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Index extends Component
{
    public $name, $slug, $status;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [

        'name' => 'required|string',
        'slug' => 'required|string',
        'status' => 'nullable',
        ];
    }

    public function resetInput()
    {
        $this->name = NULL;
        $this->slug = NULL;
        $this->status = NULL;
    }

    public function storeBrand()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate();
                 
        Brand::create([
            'name' => $this->name,
            'slug' => Str::slug($this->slug),
            'status' => $this->status == true ? '1':'0',
        ]);

        session()->flash('message','Brand Added Successfully');
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal');
        $this->resetInput();
   
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.brand.index');
                          
    }
}
```